# PHP Poll Script with Hourly Reset & Multiple Voting

Tags: php, voting-system

I'm looking for a script (or one that I can easily modify to do this) that allows visitors to vote 10 times every hour or day. After they've hit that limit, it can compare it to the IP or a cookie and say they've voted too much.

I don't need it to be bulletproof in terms of people abusing it by deleting the cookie or masking their IP. I just want them to be able to vote 10 times in the course of a predetermined amount of time before they can vote again.

I've looked for two weeks for a script like this, to no avail.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are some impressive php code available for this purpose. you can choose according to you requirement.

top 1 http://www.dbscripts.net/poll/

top 2 http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/free-php-ajax-poll-script-zoki-poll/

top 3 http://www.hotscripts.com/listing/php-poll-with-images/